# I'm looking for an alternative solution for common HTML contact form on the client's side

Tags: javascript, html, forms, client-side, client-side-scripting

I'm creating a form. As of right now I have simple MAILTO form that just open the email client.

I wonder if there are any better ways of creating a form by avoiding using MAILTO? A nice client-side contact form which doesn't use MAILTO.

I can only use JavaScript and HTML. I can't use any server-side scripts.

What are the alternatives?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a server-side ability not available on the client-side.

Comment: "I can't use any server-side scripts", on your own server, or on any server in the world?

Comment: @Neil McGuigan, site is meant to just run from PC, it isn't published to the Internet. It's a school assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go a hosted route...there are a few options out there. You could suggest social media options (contact via Facebook, twitter, etc).

But email is nice too. As a user, I prefer contacting people via email rather than filling out another annoying form.

But as Kolink states, if you don't want to use email, you HAVE to have some sort of server-based system...be it your own or hosted elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a service like [jotform](http://www.jotform.com/) or [wufoo](http://wufoo.com/) to handle the form, I know jotform will email you upon each submission if you set it up to do so. You can also use [google docs](https://docs.google.com/) to create forms that store to a spreadsheet, that way you can load it in excel or any other app that accepts `csv` files.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across [SquareSend.com](https://squaresend.com).

Answer (score 0):

Without any server-side scripts, there are precisely zero alternatives.

Comment: Oh dear.. That's a bummer. How about JavaScript that just saves the messages to the file?

Comment: JavaScript cannot access the filesystem. Otherwise every spammer on the internet would be uploading your hard drive.

Comment: I think HelpNeeder needs to specify **why** he/she cannot use a server-side script ("difficult to install", "company policy", whatever). The alternative would be to post to an external host (which, in turn, will ofcourse be running a server-side script). I find it hard to believe no-one would be offering this kind of "service", maybe for a small price. Either way; "precisely zero" is maybe a little blunt.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: @RobIII, the problem is that my site is not published on the net, rather it's my portfolio assignment and is meant to just run from the PC, not Web.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: You can run most (any?) server-side script perfectly "locally". As I said before: please specify **why** you (think you) can't use a server-side script.

Comment: who says you need to HOST the server-side stuff yourself? there's plenty of form-sites out there that do just that.

Comment: @RobIII, well I didn't know that I can run scripts with out being posted to the net now be on the Web server. You mind sharing what scripts can I use locally?

Comment: @HelpNeeder You can run just about anything locally. Now if you'd only had mentioned the language you'd like to use... But here's another suggestion: read the manual/help/documentation of your preferred language on how to go about running it locally before asking. At least please make an effort *before* asking ;-) Assuming your preference is PHP and you're running Windows: you might want to take a look at projects like WAMP wich make it a lot easier to set up.

Comment: @RobIII, Well, I'm not sure my teacher will want to install PHP before grading my project. It must be installed, right?